# How to align text underneath each other in hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css

After completing my hamburger menu and setting it to show up only when the screen's max-width is 600px, the links won't stay under each other, they are aligned next to each other and it's not possible to click on most of them either.

What code can I add to make them neater when minimizing the page?
Attaching my code for reference...thanks!

```
 <nav role="navigation" class="nav">



              <input class="trigger" type="checkbox" id="mainNavButton">
              <label for="mainNavButton" onclick></label>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="musicaltheatre.html">Musical Theatre</a></li>
                      <li><a href="afterschool.html">After School</a></li>
                          <li><a href="holidayprogrammes">HolidayProgrammes</a>
                        </ul>

                      <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                      <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
                      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="where.html">Where</a></li>
                      <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
                    </ul>

                     <figcaption>

                        <p>Welcome!</p>

                    </figcaption>    

            </nav>

                <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/maridrama_logo.png" class="centre"></a></div>

            </div>
```

```
.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(assets/images/matthijs-smit-574921-unsplash.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.nav{

    background: background: url(assets/images/matthijs-smit-574921-unsplash.jpg);
}



.nav figcaption {
    padding: 10em;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.35s;
    transition: background-color 0.35s;
}

.nav figcaption::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    content: '';
}


.nav figcaption::before,
.nav p {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "Franklin Gothic Demi Cond";
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}



.nav:hover figcaption::before,
.nav:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.nav:hover figcaption {
    background-color: rgba(58,52,42,0);
}



body {
  -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;

}

@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
  from {
    padding: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
/* needed for checkbox hack */
h1, p {
  color: white;
}

.nav ul {
  display: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;

}
.nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 150px;



}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #96C7ED;
  transition: all ease;
}
.nav ul li:last-of-type a {
  border-right: 0px;


}
.nav ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 2px;

}
.nav ul li ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 3.125em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}
.nav input.trigger {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
.nav input.trigger:checked ~ ul, .nav input.trigger:checked ~ ul li ul {
  display: block !important;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav input.trigger:checked ~ ul, .nav input.trigger:checked ~ ul li ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
.nav label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 2em;
  padding: .45em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #96C7ED;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #bfe1fb;
}
.nav label:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: .2em;
  content: "\2261";
  font-size: 1.8em;
  color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .nav ul {

    display: -ms-flexbox;
    flex-direction: -ms-row;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

 .nav ul li {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;

    -ms-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;

    flex: 1;
  }

 .nav ul li ul {
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 200;
  }
  .nav ul li ul li {
    text-align: center;
    height: 65px;

  }
  .nav ul li ul li ul {
    z-index: 300;
    top: 0px;
    left: 12.4em;
  }
  .nav ul li ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
  }
  .nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .nav label {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: i tested your code if you meant the links they are under each other only the hovered ones are on the right

Comment: how can I fix that?

Comment: just remove float right

Comment: yes that works but the thing is that when you maximize the page again, the links get on top of each other

Comment: ok ill try do it on desktop and mobile

Comment: did you remove the 2 float:right?

Comment: yeah i can see the problem you have to change some css

Answer (score 0):

```css
`fdfd`
 enter code here bfb fbfb fgf di v and s exc ruinnd  dsjbjcjnc sndb
    .master-grid {
  display: grid;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 4px black;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(70px, 1fr));
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    "sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar"
    "content content content content"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}
    .content {
  grid-area: content;
  justify-content:center;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(
    270deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.11808473389355745) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7903536414565826) 10%,
    rgba(168, 168, 168, 1) 100%);
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
text align center
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
`fdfd`
 enter code here bfb fbfb fgf di v and s exc ruinnd  dsjbjcjnc sndb
    .master-grid {
  display: grid;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 4px black;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(70px, 1fr));
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    "sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar"
    "content content content content"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}
    .content {
  grid-area: content;
  justify-content:center;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(
    270deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.11808473389355745) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7903536414565826) 10%,
    rgba(168, 168, 168, 1) 100%);
  padding: 1rem;
}
```